# How to pass type arguments to an indexed type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to get the return type of a generic function in a class.

For example,

```
declare class Test {
    open<T, R>(t1: T, t2: R): T | R;
}

type TestType<T, R> = (Test['open'])<T, R>;

type TestTypeReturn = ReturnType<TestType<number, number>>;
```

However I get errors on the 4th non-blank line around at `...])<T, R>` saying that a semi-colon is expected. I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible. Anyone know?

Comment: It looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: It's not a compiler bug; you can only specify the type parameters of a generic function when you call it.  Given a generic function type like `type F = <T>(x: T)=>void`, there is no such type as `F<T>`.

Comment: @jcalz "you can **only** specify the type parameters of a generic function when you call it" --- are you sure? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAFQHxQLxQBQEo0oQbgFgAoE0SWeZNWRJfIA

Comment: Those aren’t generic functions, though.  They are generic type aliases that refer to non-generic functions. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably for the specific example shown you could manually write out the desired type, like:

```
type TestTypeManual<T, R> = (t1: T, t2: R) => T | R;
type TestTypeReturnManual = ReturnType<TestTypeManual<number, number>>; // number
```

But you want to get the compiler to do this for you.

---

TypeScript's type system lacks the expressiveness needed to represent the relationship between a concrete type alias referring to a generic function type like `type GenFunc = <T>(x: T)=>T` and a generic type alias referring to a concrete function type like `type GenAlias<T> = (x:T)=>T`. You cannot specify the type parameter(s) of a generic function without calling the function.  So with the above, even though you can *call* a function of type `GenFunc` like `genFunc<string>("hello")`, there's no such *type* as `GenFunc<string>`.  There is an open [suggestion (microsoft/TypeScript#17574)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) which might allow such higher rank type manipulation, but I don't know if we can expect any movement there.

For now, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this *purely at the type level*.

---

If you don't mind some possible hacks that have some effect on the emitted JavaScript, you could take advantage of some support for [inferring generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) added in TypeScript 3.4.  Here's how I might do it.  First, introduce a function declaration somewhere like this:

```
// you could just declare this instead of implementing it, but whatever:
function magicThunk<A extends any[], R>(f: (...args: A) => R): () => (...args: A) => R {
    return () => f; 
}
```

The `magicThunk()` function presumably just takes a callback function `f` and returns a new no-arg function that returns `f`, which doesn't seem very magical (but is a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk#Functional_programming), at least).  But if you call `magicThunk()` with a generic function, an interesting thing happens as of TS3.4:

```
const genericIdentity = <T>(x: T) => x; // <T>(x: T) => T
const thunkIdentity = magicThunk(genericIdentity); // <T>() => (x: T) => T
```

The returned function is *also* generic, but the generic type parameter(s) have been moved *outward* one level.  Now you can call the thunked generic function and specify it's type parameter(s), getting a non-generic function:

```
const stringIdentity = thunkIdentity<string>(); // (x: string) => string;
```

So this is exactly the operation of "specify the type parameters of a generic function without calling it", as we want.

Anyway we're almost there... the last step is to create a new *generic* `class`, allowing us to bring some type parameters into scope without putting them directly on another function.  Here's how I'd do it for your `Test["open"]` type:

```
class TransformTest<T, R> {
    open = magicThunk(new Test().open)<T, R>()
}
```

And now the type of `TransformTest<T, R>.open` should be the type you're looking for:

```
type TestType<T, R> = TransformTest<T, R>["open"]; // (t1: T, t2: R) => T | R
type TestTypeReturn = ReturnType<TestType<number, number>>; // number
```

So that all works.  Note that you never need to actually call `magicThunk()` or construct an instance of `TransformTest` in your code (that's good because I don't think `open` will be properly bound); the compiler is doing all the work you need at design time; it just has to be made to go through the motions of evaluating the types of code that will be emitted.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwComQF3gbwCh5j4B7ABxADsAedAGngCUA+ACmwEYAuDR7AEy8mASl7p4AH2YBuAgF94RAtgCelDFmzp1IALJQqAVygQ6jVvAC88Djz7xBwkdZYYpslbs04dlJiDYRjBUBsam1syBwVR+IHRacWEmZsYAtgBGIDCM6VkwLCwy8AD0JfB52QQEAGZGVGDYAJakVPBpUADmTWDoABb1ANY0AILwIAAe2NTAaIaqANoAuhbsNbxsAHTbsJ3IvCMuVm6iG0duWzswewfnzPhEJHBBIbZ3NXLy1WXwyH2kAHd4AC+lBcB1ur0BlRBvBgKQsAQwK0cPBOtRsj0AJKgKjNNSROjsCbiO4TYo-IlsEkYO7oJEo3DYaGDHHUfGqSIQnr9IZsdFUTFgNl4ppqEQU8pUu7U0muDAMqionAwJpUToijmRZlDTVi1Q0FVqzrsCWlcqy37YVXqu5G9VyAg-PrZEAAcjm8AAbtlkC02qQaj5cCDXY4XWiMaqwI5vORYFA0oFffBYAg0qQfcB4EZyPA1dhSOGEEhUHCQDUqEjoGX0DBDMgaqQYGlMDhzMw3IQSGRKG0bNyoXzBUC29g2CJNhRqCIO6wJwpvuVDNmXXAPfBVKRgrHKPsvBox3E524bHWG02W2OTwsAETTqi3paS2xccT8ITMOkeJgHhBH3QAhefsomA48AMoGhKhyCojEybJChfaDqiAA)

Comment: Oh, wow, thank you. I'll play around with this a bit. The actual open function itself and enclosing class are defined by a third party (Angular) so at a first glance the Thunk idea is probably the most ideal. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't accomplish what I needed to do, but that's because we're still on Typescript 3.2. But this solves the question as asked so I'm marking it as the solution. Thanks again!